# How do I skip running the single task probing job in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have very simple pyspark mapPartitions job that's split across 200 workers. The tasks are completed independent from one another.  Each task can take 2 hours to finish so I prefer them to run in parallel from the beginning. But somehow pyspark always tries to run a single task probing job before deploying the full 200 workers. Is there any way to turn off that "smart" behavior? I tried a lot of different methods, but the single task probing job is very persistent.

As can be seen from the screen shot, Stage 1 only has a single task. And if I look into the log, it's just running shard 0 out of the 200 shards. Is there any way to make pyspark just run a good old mapper only job without speculative single task probing (or whatever that is called)?

A few things I have tried:

- setting `spark.speculation` to false
- setting `scheduler.mode` to FAIR
- add more workers than the number of shards

```py
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "60g")
conf.set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "20g")
conf.set("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "20g")
conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "250")
conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "200")
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "200")
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors", "300")
conf.set("executor-cores", '8')

conf.set('spark.speculation', 'false')
conf.set('spark.scheduler.mode', 'FAIR')
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport()
    .config(conf=conf)
    .appName("My-App")
    .getOrCreate()
)

num_workers = 200
data = [(t,) for t in range(num_workers)]
schema = ['global_shard_idx']


input_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
t_df
  .repartition(num_workers)
  .rdd
  .mapPartitionsWithIndex(resolve_partition)
  .toDF(['partition_idx'])
  .write
  .format('orc')
  .option('header', 'true')
  .mode('overwrite')
  .saveAsTable('temp.dummy_table')
```

[image]